# perl code for splitting a single file by matching charater into multiple files

Tags: perl

i want to split a large data file into multiple files where ever it matches a '^' character.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  
use strict;  
print "enter the data file name";  
chomp( my $a=<STDIN> );  
open (<READ>,"$a")| "error";  
while ($line=<READ>)  
 {  
  my @array=split("        ",$line) unless ^ ;
```

after splitting of the data file. A total of 23 files will be created

Comment: You haven't really given enough information.  How do you want the output files to be named?  Why are you splitting the lines?  The easiest way to match `^` is `$line =~ /\^/`.  Do you want the line containing `^` to go in the old file or the new one?  Or part in one and part in another?

Comment: the files can be named in any wa say file1 file2........ and i want to store my large file into smaller one and the breaking point of the files is "^" tha is where the line will read this charater it wil break and rest of the data will be stored in a new file ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight different answer from saiprathapreddy.obula's:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($file) = @ARGV;

open(my $input, "<$file");

local $/ = "^";

my $i = 0;

while(<>){
    chomp;

    $i++;

    open(my $output, ">file$i.txt");
    print $output "$_"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;

open(FILE,'AUTOSAR.txt');
local $/;
my $var = <FILE>;
my @arr = split('\^',$var);
my $i=0;

foreach (@arr) {
    $i++;
    open(FILE1,">$i.txt");
    print FILE1 $_;
    close FILE1;
}

close FILE;
```

Comment: You need `my $var = <FILE>;`.  Otherwise, I think your solution works.  To explain, this code is slurping the entire file into a single variable `$var`, which it does by `local $/;`, which sets the end-of-line character to be undefined.  It then splits on `^` and writes each fragment to a separate file starting from `0.txt`.  The only concern is the memory footprint if it is a really large file.  Also, you can `close FILE` as soon as you read into `$var`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$,="";
$"="";
my $i=1;
open OUT ,">DATA_${i}.txt";
while(<>){
    chomp;
    my @F=split(/\^/);
    if(@F==1){
            print OUT $_,"\n";
    }
    elsif(@F>1){
            $i++;
            close OUT;
            open OUT ,">DATA_${i}.txt";
            print OUT "@F[1..$#F] \n";
    }
}
close OUT;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it loses the caret characters, though it's still not clear what the intent is if there is a line like `abc^def^ghi`.  Your program will put `abc` in the previous file and then the next file will have `defghi`.  Arguably, there should be another file with just `def`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up and tested version of the program of saiprathapreddy.obula.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,'AUTOSAR.txt');

local $/;
my $var = <FILE>;
close FILE;

my @arr = split('\^',$var);
my $i=0;

foreach (@arr) {
    $i++;
    open(FILE1,">$i.txt");
    print FILE1;
    close FILE1;
}
```